# How to use Facebook's Graph API to pull Audience Demographics

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Trying to figure out how to use Facebook Audience API to pull the demographics for a specific page.

The information they provide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/audience-insights-query/ does not work via the Graph explorer.

Could anyone out there point me in the right direction as to how to grab the **overall** audience demographics for a page?

Is it only possible to pull these via *page_impressions_by_age_gender*?

Comment: I guess there is a an error in the doc which says to use this api:
GET v2.7/...?fields={fieldname_of_type_AudienceInsightsQuery}

Answer (score 1):

You can pull these via:

- {page_id}/insights/page_fans_gender_age
- {page_id}/insights/page_fans_country

..and others. See the Page User Demographics section here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/insights

Comment: Given that you seemed to figure out some of the cryptic Facebook Audience Insights API documentation, do you have any comment on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333909/facebook-graph-audience-insights-queries I appreciate any help!

Comment: I hope you help
https://www.agorapulse.com/blog/facebook-audience-insights-targeting

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/697694370291354?helpref=faq_content