# Facebook Graph audience insights queries

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I found some intriguing Facebook Graph API documentation here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/audience-insights-query
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/audience-insights-lifestyle/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/audience-insights-lifestyles/ (plural)
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audience-insights-api/v2.8

I think the results of those queries will be really powerful and could help my business.

But all of their examples are unclear and nonfunctional, such as:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '...?fields={fieldname_of_type_AudienceInsightsLifestyle}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

What would be a working example of something that should go where `...` is currently and where it says `{fieldname_of_type_AudienceInsightsLifestyle}`?

And how can I find a full list of valid values for those?

Comment: Hi Ryan, did you ever found any solution or answer?

Comment: @senty No, still disappointed by FB docs.